# Peak-to-Peak amplitude of sinus wave signal as function of time in LabVIEW

Tags: signal-processing, labview

A current source is exciting a Loud by an AC current of ±5mA. The voltage through the loud is measured using the NI data acquisition. The resistance of the loud changes with time, the peak-to-peak amplitude of the voltage signal changes accordingly. How to define the relationship between the loud's resistance and the voltage peak-to-peak amplitude?! in other words, how can I plot the graph of signal's peak-to-peak amplitude as a function of time in LabView?

Comment: Have you already got a clear measure of the peak-peak amplitude? That is, can you display it as a live number value?

Answer (score 0):

1. measure with appropriate Sample-Rate, at least 10 times higher than the max. frequency of your signal.
2. use a DAQ, that has "synchronous sampling"
3. measure current and voltage (synchronously with high sample rate). You can use either a shunt or a current transducer for current measurement
4. Sample in "Blocks". This means: let the DAQ device store e.g. 10k Values (at a Sample rate of 100kHz) in it's internal memory, and read that buffer every 100 ms. Go to the Example finder (Help -> Find exampes) and look for "continous analog measurement" examples.
5. calculate the RMS-Value of both signals of each block and plot that in a graph. If you want it simple, feed both signals into a "Chart".

if the current is constant (which should be a strait line in the graph!), the voltage should rise over time, when the inner resistance of the loudspeaker rises ...

Note: be aware, that with the example numbers above (100kHz SR, Blocksizte 10k) calculating the RMS value will produce wrong results, when your signal main frequency is below 10 Hz!